# Sonata Admin Bundle + Sonata User Bundle : Override Login Form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I know this subject is already open, but after few month theire is no answer at all, and when i tried answer to know if this author got any solutions ... My comment was deleted. So i'm theire to post again this problem.

I'm using for my administration SonataAdminBunbdle and SonataUserBundle.
Everything is working almost fine, beside few specific things.

Now, my problem. I wanna override the default login form.
But, even everything i tried, nothing works.

1) I tryed to override the FOSUserBundle login form like said in [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html).

I put in correct path this file

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
    AZERTY
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Deleted completely the original login form, but nothing change i still have the same default login form.

2) using the same method for [SonataAdminBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/templates.html) but theire's nothing for login form templates.

3) Then again one time for [SonataUserBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/profile_edition.html) but i didn't find anything to override the login form template.

I'm out of solutions, that's why i'm theire to asking help.
I find how to change the login form by going directly modify my vendor's files:

```
// vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig    

{% extends base_template %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="connection">
        <form action="{{ path("sonata_user_admin_security_check") }}" method="post">

            {% if error %}
                <div class="alert alert-error">{{ error|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}</div>
            {% endif %}

            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="big sonata-medium"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="big sonata-medium" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
               <label for="remember_me">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                    {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

So, finally i wanna override this specific file, or find a way to change the template path in a configuration file.

Anyone has already override this login form template ?

Comment: Have you tried to create a corresponding view folder in app > resources ?

Like :

app > Resources > sonata-project > user-bundle > Resources > views > Admin > Security > login.html.twig

Don't forget to clear cache.

Not really like that of course, more like SonaUserBundle > etc but I did not need to do this recently

Comment: Thx for your answer @Delphine, i tried almost all combinaisons i can imagine

- app > Resources > AdminUserBundle > Resources > views > Admin > Security

- app > Resources > SonataUserBundle > Resources > views > Admin

- app > Resources > sonata-project > user-bundle > Resources > views > Security

- app > Resources > views > AdminUserBundle > Resources > views > Admin > Security

- app > Resources > views > SonataUserBundle > Resources > views > Admin > Security

Nothing changed, still all the time the same default login form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you place your custom `login.html.twig` into:

`app/Resources/SonataUserBundle/views/Admin/Security`

it will work.

You can read [more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) about overriding templates in Symfony.

Comment: Thx a lot ! I thought i already tried this, but seem's i forgot this case ... Thx a lot.

Comment: Even if you're using Symfony 4, DON'T try to move template to `templates/bundles` etc, don't waste your time! Use this answer!

Answer (score 1):

1/ Ok ! I know you made several searches but have you tried this :

```
Resources/
├── ApplicationSonataUserBundle
│   └── views
│       | 
│       └── Security
│           └── login.html.twig
```

According to your comment, I don't see this solution.

**UPDATE** :

`ApplicationSonataUserBundle` is an extend. I use to do that with SonataMediaBundle.

For example, in ApplicationSonataMediaBundle.php :

```
class ApplicationSonataMediaBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SonataMediaBundle';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx again for your help.

For your 1st point. I use easy-extend-bundle to make an extend as you suggest. Generating few files/folders in app/Application. Class ApplicationSonataUserBundle with correct parent name "SonataUserBundle", but even with my custom template, i still got the default login form.

For the 2nd, it's not working, i got an error message : "Unrecognized option "templates" under "sonata_user" ". So i can't even choose what kind of template use. Same for "sonata_user", if i try to put "login" in "templates" path configuration, "Unrecognized option "login" under "templates" "

Comment: Ok ! That's weird. Apparently, you have to override `FOSUserBundle` template, not `SonataUserBundle` one like I suggested.

Adding a `login.html.twig` template here `app\Resources\views\FOSUserBundle\views\Security\login.html.twig` does not work either ?

PS : don't forget to clear the cache

Comment: Thx for your help @Delphine we was so close. Seem's i forgot to try the case suggested by E1dar.